# SSL certificate error when trying to access any of my self hosted domains on my home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssl, certificate

I have a home server running Nextcloud and Bitwarden. To host the domains I use SWAG, which uses Let's Encrypt as an auto SSL cert provider. These domains work perfectly outside of my home network. However, when trying to access any of them with my home network, I get "Access Error: Unauthorized". When clicking on the HTTPS error, I get a "Certificate not valid". Upon checking the certificate, I see it's issued by my router's provider (ZTE). I already dug through all the router's settings (ZTE MF286D in case anyone wants to dig) but found nothing about certs. Weirdly enough though, a friend of mine with a different router, but from the same company, doesn't have this problem. What are my best bets here? Unfortunately changing the router is not one of them since it's tied to the sim card inside it.

Comment: @Ramhound I use a self hosted DNS provider (Pihole), so unfortunately that's not it. I also don't have an option to trust the certificate.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm accessing the domains using the domain name that I also use outside my home network. Accessing them using the local IP loads them correctly but they require connecting via HTTPS to actually use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior.

Your router does not support NAT hairpinning and thus forwards the traffic to itself rather than your internal ip address.

Although replacing the router is an option, there are other options too.

If you host a local DNS server, you can create an entry in the local DNS server for your domain and point it to the LAN ip address. This will overrule the domain and make it work correctly, but limit its scope only to your own local area network.

If you can't run a local DNS server, you can still make it work on a per-computer-basis by adding your domain with the correct LAN IP address in your hosts file.

Keep in mind, you do NOT want to use the IP Address as the WAN IP address, as that would not make a difference and the router gets confused when it sends traffic out and receives it back instantly, thus ignoring it and giving the router's ip back.

Comment: I use Pihole as local DNS, but doing it this way can I access the HTTPS version of the site using the local IP? Because both Nextcloud and Bitwarden won't work unless you connect using HTTPS.

Comment: Yes, of course, that's the whole idea.

Comment: I'm quite confused on what IP address I should put though. I tried using 192.168.3.10, which is the static IP I assigned to my server, but that still gives me the same problem so I guess that's not it. Where do I get the correct IP?

Comment: No, that is the correct IP Address. ping the domain to ensure that it resolves correctly, then clear your browser's cache so it refreshes there too. Also, make sure your local DNS server is the pi-hole, although I'm sure you would've known that already if it wasn't the case. BTW, if your local server is not responsible for the SSL Certificate, then the certificate cannot be used locally, only externally.

Comment: Ping returns correctly. Cache has been cleared and pihole is the only DNS in my router and traffic is going through correctly.  Still not working unfortunately. The local server is responsible for handing out the certificates.

Comment: Okay, I also needed to add the subdomains to the local DNS, but it worked. It's certainly more of a bandaid rather than an actual fix, but at least it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure about it being a bandaid. Its common practice really. We deploy routers that can do nat hairpinning, yet we usually use the build-in DNS server to fix these things instead.